# FEniCS: check if function is globally greater than 0

Tags: fenics

Given a Dolfin `Function` `u` on a mesh, I'd like to check if it is greater than 0 throughout the mesh. I noticed that the expression

```
u > 0
```

is an object of the type

```
GT(Coefficient(FiniteElement('Lagrange', Domain(Cell('triangle', 2), 'triangle_multiverse', 2, 2), 2, None), 0), Zero((), (), {}))
```

How can I evaluate that thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is piecewise linear, an easy check would be the following:

```
print u.vector().min()
```

This would also work as a good approximation for other spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're using the Python interface, in which case `u` is both a DOLFIN Function object and a UFL object (it inherits from both). The type information you're seeing is related to UFL.

You can evaluate the function `u` at an arbitrary point:

```
f = u((0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
```

if DOLFIN is configured with CGAL.

I don't know how you could check that the solution is strictly positive everywhere for arbitrary element type, but you could do a pretty good check integrating a UFL conditional,

```
c = conditional(lt(u, 0), 1, 0)

# This should be zero if u > 0
print assemble(c*dx)
```

Conditional UFL statements are presented in http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4047.

Comment: Last line should be assemble(c*dx).

Comment: Are you shure that quadrature rule will sample every possible negative region for arbitrary element supported in FEniCS?